# Compare System.Version in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a case where I have to make a decision in script based on comparing versions
Consider this example:

```
PS C:\>
[version]$SomeVersion='1.1.1'
[version]$OtherVersion='1.1.1.0'

PS C:\> $SomeVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      1      1      -1      

PS C:\> $OtherVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      1      1      0       

PS C:\>$SomeVersion -ge $OtherVersion
False
```

I would like to omit revision when comparing objects of type System.Version
I Can't find any sane way of doing that.
Is there any?

Note - I've tried doing :

```
PS C:\> ($scriptversion |select major,minor,build) -gt ($currentVersion|select major,minor,build)

Cannot compare "@{Major=1; Minor=1; Build=1}" to "@{Major=1; Minor=1; 
Build=1}" because the objects are not the same type or the object "@{Major=1; 
Minor=1; Build=1}" does not implement "IComparable".
At line:1 char:1
+ ($scriptversion |select major,minor,build) -gt ($currentVersion |sele ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSObjectCompareTo
```

when I try to override revision number with 0 it says that it's read-only property... 
I have a workaround But I hoped to do it better with system.version

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [three argument `System.Version` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.-ctor?view=netframework-4.0) to make new instances with the relevant properties:

```
[Version]::new($scriptversion.Major,$scriptversion.Minor,$scriptversion.Build) -gt [Version]::new($currentVersion.Major,$currentVersion.Minor,$currentVersion.Build)
```

Or you can go the verbose way with `New-Object`:

```
$NormalizedScriptVersion = New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList $scriptversion.Major,$scriptversion.Minor,$scriptversion.Build
$NormalizedCurrentVersion = New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList $currentVersion.Major,$currentVersion.Minor,$currentVersion.Build

$NormalizedScriptVersion -gt $NormalizedCurrentVersion
```

Use whichever you find more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to convert Version object to comparable string:

```
filter Convert-VersionToComparableText { '{0:0000000000}{1:0000000000}{2:0000000000}' -f $_.Major, $_.Minor, $_.Build }
$SomeVersion = [Version]'1.1.1' | Convert-VersionToComparableText
$OtherVersion = [Version]'1.1.1' | Convert-VersionToComparableText
$SomeVersion -ge $OtherVersion
$SomeVersion = [Version]'1.2.1' | Convert-VersionToComparableText
$OtherVersion = [Version]'1.1.1' | Convert-VersionToComparableText
$SomeVersion -ge $OtherVersion
$SomeVersion = [Version]'1.1.1' | Convert-VersionToComparableText
$OtherVersion = [Version]'1.2.1' | Convert-VersionToComparableText
$SomeVersion -ge $OtherVersion
```

The output:

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the answer looks better than mine solution splitting version into [INT[]] and  comparing each ...